# When I launch a browser in debug mode on my asp.net mvc project, can I tell VS2013 to navigate it directly to a certain part of the site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I've been working for weeks building/debugging a critical part of the site. Lets say I want to navigate directly to here:

~/Critical/Create/100

This "edits" record 100.

The cshtml file that runs this is called Create.cshtml. I did notice if I have it focused in the IDE that I will go directly to ~/Critical/Create

This isn't good enough, because /Create will go to the blank record creation screen.

Is there some setting somewhere that I can set that will force the debug session to go directly to some url, no matter which .cshtml file is focused? Ideally, then I could go to ~/Critical/Create/Random and load a random record.

This would save me about 5-10 seconds clicking my way there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click properties on your MVC project .csproj.

Edit the Web / Start Action to have the specific page. The value you want here is the URL route that you want to load. I'm not sure if this is your actual route, but whatever the URL is, put that here. No leading `/` character.

Be sure there's no other value in any other box in the Start Action section.

[image]

Comment: thats very .. discoverable. I'm embarrassed.

Comment: Lol, I was once berated by a well known character on SO for failing to click through all the menus to find out what was obvious to him.